# sender isn't defined for the type list <message>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 clasees one for user

```
class User {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;

  User({
     this.id ,
     this.name ='',
     this.imageUrl='',
  });
}
```

and class message

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat/models/user_models.dart';
class Message {
  final String time; // Would usually be type DateTime or Firebase Timestamp in production apps
  final String text;
  final bool? isLiked;
  final bool? unread;
  final User? sender;


  Message(
      {
         this.sender,
         this.time='',
          this.text='',
         this.isLiked,
     this.unread,
  }
  );

}
```

in class message I have defined a list of message

```
List <Message> Chats = [
  Message(
    sender: james,
    time: '5:30 PM',
    text: 'Hey, how\'s it going? What did you do today?',
    isLiked: false,
    unread: true,
  ),
  Message(
    sender: olivia,
    time: '4:30 PM',
    text: 'Hey, how\'s it going? What did you do today?',
    isLiked: false,
    unread: true,
  ),];
```

and in the main I have called this list of course I imported the path of the previous classes the problem is when I call *Chats.sender.name* it does not recognize sender and the error message is The getter 'sender' isn't defined for the type 'list'

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick an element from the list to access the `sender`. Try using a `forEach`.

```dart
Chats.forEach((e) => print(e.sender));
```

For `ListView.builder`:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(Chats[index].sender?.name ?? 'No Value'),
  itemCount: Chats.length,
),
```

Comment: actually i just need the name so i have putted in listview builder

Comment: (itemCount: Chats.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context , int index )
                            {
                            return Text(
                              Chats.sender.name,

Comment: ib/widgets/recent_chat.dart:24:38: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'Message' which excludes null.
 - 'Message' is from 'package:second/models/message_model.dart' ('lib/models/message_model.dart').
                                Chats[index]?.sender?.name ?? 'No Value'

Comment: i get that warning  but it's work ... so here ? is to avoid null variable is it necessary to use it in flutter cause we i remove it from even the definition of variable in class it don't work

Comment: you could remove `?` after `]`.